# Google Maps Renders KML inverse of Google Earth

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been struggling how to solve a problem with how google maps renders a KML polygon. In Good Earth, it renders the polygon correctly like this: [image]

But in Google maps, when I add this to the map, it incorrectly looks like this:

[image]

Surprisingly, this is made of 32 points which go across Africa, NOT the Pacific Ocean!

Why in the world is this being rendered inversely when I specifically indicate the points? Is it just simply ignoring them?

I created a JSFiddle for this here: https://jsfiddle.net/qsz5ec5y/1/

The KML file is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27946381/testzone.kml

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the Google Maps KML parser is broken.

[Your bug report on the issues list](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7872)

You KML has a well defined polygon with several points on each side (which should be more than enough to tell it which way the polygon goes):

```
142.207023447954498,-24.785157829137347 112.016594491497187,-24.785157829137347 81.826165535039934,-24.785157829137347 51.635736578582652,-24.785157829137347 21.44530762212537,-24.785157829137347 -8.745121334331884,-24.785157829137347 -38.935550290789166,-24.785157829137347 -69.125979247246434,-24.785157829137347 -99.316408203703702,-24.785157829137347 -99.316408203703702,-19.291993899650947 -99.316408203703702,-13.798829970164547 -99.316408203703702,-8.305666040678148 -99.316408203703702,-2.812502111191748 -99.316408203703702,2.680661818294652 -99.316408203703702,8.173825747781052 -99.316408203703702,13.666989677267452 -99.316408203703702,19.160153606753852 -69.125979247246434,19.160153606753852 -38.935550290789166,19.160153606753852 -8.745121334331884,19.160153606753852 21.44530762212537,19.160153606753852 51.635736578582652,19.160153606753852 81.826165535039934,19.160153606753852 112.016594491497187,19.160153606753852 142.207023447954498,19.160153606753852 142.207023447954498,13.666989677267452 142.207023447954498,8.173825747781052 142.207023447954498,2.680661818294652 142.207023447954498,-2.812502111191748 142.207023447954498,-8.305666040678148 142.207023447954498,-13.798829970164547 142.207023447954498,-19.291993899650947 142.207023447954498,-24.785157829137347
```

[fiddle showing points above](http://jsfiddle.net/6ct5p05n/)

Your KML also works in [geoxml3 (which renders it as native google.maps.Polygon objects)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?lat=-16.848698&lng=50.976558&zoom=1&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/so_20150403_testzone.kml) (if you load the KmlLayer you can see the issue)

**code snippet showing your rectangle rendered both as KML and a "normal" google.maps.Polygon:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var ctaLayer;
var poly;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var path = [];
  var coordsStr = kmlCoords.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < coordsStr.length; i++) {
    var coords = coordsStr[i].split(',');
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0]);
    path.push(latLng);
    bounds.extend(latLng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
      title: latLng.toUrlValue(6)
    });
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: path,
    map: map
  });
  ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27946381/testzone.kml'
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function toggleKml() {
  if (ctaLayer.getMap() == null) {
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);
  } else {
    ctaLayer.setMap(null);
  }
}

function togglePolygon() {
  if (poly.getMap() == null) {
    poly.setMap(map);
  } else {
    poly.setMap(null);
  }
}

var kmlCoords = "142.207023447954498,-24.785157829137347 112.016594491497187,-24.785157829137347 81.826165535039934,-24.785157829137347 51.635736578582652,-24.785157829137347 21.44530762212537,-24.785157829137347 -8.745121334331884,-24.785157829137347 -38.935550290789166,-24.785157829137347 -69.125979247246434,-24.785157829137347 -99.316408203703702,-24.785157829137347 -99.316408203703702,-19.291993899650947 -99.316408203703702,-13.798829970164547 -99.316408203703702,-8.305666040678148 -99.316408203703702,-2.812502111191748 -99.316408203703702,2.680661818294652 -99.316408203703702,8.173825747781052 -99.316408203703702,13.666989677267452 -99.316408203703702,19.160153606753852 -69.125979247246434,19.160153606753852 -38.935550290789166,19.160153606753852 -8.745121334331884,19.160153606753852 21.44530762212537,19.160153606753852 51.635736578582652,19.160153606753852 81.826165535039934,19.160153606753852 112.016594491497187,19.160153606753852 142.207023447954498,19.160153606753852 142.207023447954498,13.666989677267452 142.207023447954498,8.173825747781052 142.207023447954498,2.680661818294652 142.207023447954498,-2.812502111191748 142.207023447954498,-8.305666040678148 142.207023447954498,-13.798829970164547 142.207023447954498,-19.291993899650947 142.207023447954498,-24.785157829137347";
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="toggleKml();" value="toggle KML" />
<input type="button" onclick="togglePolygon();" value="toggle Polygon" />
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: OK so I am not crazy! Thanks for verifying this... I think I will post a report to Google somehow. This is very annoying.

Comment: The issues list is here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list, I didn't see this listed.

Comment: Just posted here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7872&thanks=7872&ts=1428329698
I would actually like to use your geoxml3, but I can't seem to get it working. Is there a way to contact you directly?